# 100vh 'height' property attribute is producing vertical scrolling. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the html for making the container inside my body tag to accomodate full height of the window. You can check the code here [html code i wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpwQN.png).
And here is the link of the output i got which is not desirable according to my html code:[output that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msCQU.png). You can see the scroll on the right side.

I've checked already present answers on the Stack Overflow related to this issue but i couldn't find any simple answers to this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll is contributed by `border` property , `div` default `margin`/ `padding` .

You can remove scroll by :

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped!

Comment: welcome , happy to help